# Javascript Modules SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

So I am trying to learn modules from a youtube video and I'm following along with him but for some reason my code is the exact same as his and is giving me the error

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I'm not sure if its because my directories are wrong? I have it under
This PC > Desktop > Javascript > module > js > main.js
This is the code from main.js

```
import{double} from './utils.js'

console.log(double(5))
```

I also have a index.html file located in the module folder
This is my index.html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Modules</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/dcode.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>JavaScript Modules</h1>
    <u1>
        <li>Split up your code into separate components</li>
        <li>Therefore easier to maintain and organize</li>
        <li>Supported in major browsers(excl. IE)</li>
    </u1>

    <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm trying to `import` code from my utils.js file which is in the same folder as main.js
This is my utils.js code.

```
export function double(n){
    return n * 2;
}
```

When I run the code on the main.js file is where I'm getting the error:
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: let me guess ... you are not running a Web server while you are testing this ... if files are not served with the correct mime-type, the browser will fail at recognizing these. use `npx ucdn --debug` and test on that address, or use any other one-liner server side, instead of running that html page as a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run your own webserver. An easy one is to get the [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en). You just run it, point it to your local computer folder, and it will give you a localhost port number where your computer is serving the folder. That way you can access your local folders over HTTP.

With the following folder structure:

```
/exports/
   user.html
   importer.js
   exporter.js
```

Where `user.html` is the page using the `importer.js` script, which in turn loads `exporter.js`, you use the following syntax:

**user.html**
-- the `type="module"` notation is necessary.

```
<script src="importer.js" type="module"></script>
```

**importer.js**
-- the `./` [relative notation is obligatory.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#Importing_features_into_your_script)

```
import { doStuff } from './exporter.js'

doStuff()
```

**exporter.js**
-- in a production environment, this is your library or module.

```
function doStuff() {
   console.log('Do stuff')
}

export { doStuff }
```

With a local server, the above setup will log `Do stuff` in the console.

Forgetting `type="module"` results in an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`, not having a relative URL will result in an `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "exporter.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`, and having the wrong URL results in a 404.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I have actually solved the problem the day I posted this. But it's great that the post now has an official answer in case anyone else has the same problem and comes across this. I personally used http-server/http-party from github to setup my local server. This should work as well though! Thanks.